# How does the Alpha Vantage API handle same Ticker Symbols in different exchanges?

Tags: api, alpha-vantage

Stock Ticker symbols can be the same for different stocks in different exchanges. The ticker symbol has to be unique in the exchange it is traded in, but it doesn't necessarily have to be unique across all exchanges.
How does Alpha Vantage handle this situation? I tried querying their API but I couldn't find duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Omkar: Within the U.S., I think they supply the price data consolidated across all the major exchanges.  I am not yet sure what they do about stocks listed in exchanges outside the U.S.  T.

Comment: I checked the list of listed stocks using their listing_status endpoint and found no duplicates for ticker symbols, but I did find multiple exchanges. I didn't look into it once I found this as this combination worked for my use case, but I would still like to know how they handle this.